# PSPDFKIT : Incorrect response MIME Type

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, webassembly, pspdfkit

I followed the PSPDFKit [React tutorials available here](https://github.com/PSPDFKit/pspdfkit-web-example-react)

I also copied my files to the /public directory and moved everything except pspdfkit.js from `node_modules` there and I updated my `baseUrl` variable to point to this directory.

Then when I try to run my react app locally using `npm run start` on `localhost:3000`, I get the loading animation from PSPDFkit but it hangs up and the console gives me a single error:

> Using WASM method
>
> Start http://localhost:3000/pspdfkit-lib/pspdfkit.wasm download.
>
> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to execute 'compile' on 'WebAssembly': Incorrect response MIME type. Expected 'application/wasm'.

[I know there is a trouble-shooting topic on it, found here](https://pspdfkit.com/guides/web/current/pspdfkit-for-web/troubleshooting/#response-has-unsupported-mime-type-error), but I still haven't been able to resolve my issue.

Any thoughts?

**My Component File:**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import PSPDFKitWeb from 'pspdfkit';

class PSPDFKit extends Component {
    constructor(props, context){
        super(props, context);
        this._instance = null;
        this._container = null;

        this.onRef = this.onRef.bind(this);
        this.load = this.load.bind(this);
        this.unload = this.unload.bind(this);
      }

      onRef(container) {
        this._container = container;
      }

      //function that loads PSPDFKit library when
      async load(props) {
        console.log(`Loading ${props.pdfUrl}`);
        this._instance = await PSPDFKitWeb.load({
          disableWebAssemblyStreaming: true,
          pdf: props.pdfUrl,
          container: this._container,
          licenseKey: props.licenseKey,
          baseUrl: props.baseUrl
        });
        console.log("Successfully mounted PSPDFKit", this._instance);
      }

      unload() {
        PSPDFKitWeb.unload(this._instance || this._container);
        this._instance = null;
      }

      componentDidMount() {
        this.load(this.props);
      }

      componentDidUpdate(nextProps) {
        this.unload();
        this.load(nextProps);
      }

      componentWillUnmount() {
        this.unload();
      }

      render() {
        return <div ref={this.onRef} style={{ width: "100%", height: "100%", position: "absolute" }} />;
      }
    }

export default PSPDFKit
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone that reaches this with the same problem. You might get by disabling web assembly streaming(which causes the error. react-scripts webpack dont serve wasm files in right mime type).
just pass disableWebAssemblyStreaming as true on the load method:

```
this._instance = await PSPDFKitWeb.load({
    pdf: props.pdfUrl,
    container: this._container,
    licenseKey: props.licenseKey,
    baseUrl: props.baseUrl,
    disableWebAssemblyStreaming: true, // <---- This here
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is caused by the wasm file not being served with the right content type as it is recommended here: https://pspdfkit.com/guides/web/current/pspdfkit-for-web/troubleshooting/#response-has-unsupported-mime-type-error

Open the `package.json` file and upgrade `react-scripts` to `1.1.5`, remove `node_modules`, then reinstall.

In the future, please reach out to pspdfkit.com/support/request and our support team will help you in there.

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not solve my problem, I emailed your team and attached my package.json file.